# nodejs express PUT error and number shows in every users profile

Tags: node.js, json, database, express, rapidapi

**Help please**

[This is how I write the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWjf1.png)

[PUT requested in 1 user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2vJy.png)

[Now showing that on both users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcFAZ.png)

I am trying to increase each user's "entries" number by doing PUT req. But whenever I do that for only 1 user. the number automatically increases in both users' "entries". You can understand better when you see the picture.

**Thank you so much**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here you increasing user's entry for all the users. If you want to increase only for a specific user add the increase logic inside the if condition.

For example like below

```js
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;

  let found = false;

  database.users.forEach(users => {
    if (users.id === id) {
      found = true;
      users.entries++
      return res.json(users.entries);
    }
  });
  if (!found) {
    res.status(400).json('not found');
  }
});
```